# How can I load popup widget unload or on ready?

Tags: magento2, widget, popup

I am trying to load popup widget , admin specifies it will be unload on ready . Where can I specify it must pop unload or on ready  ?

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
'mage/cookies'
], function ($, modal) {
'use strict';

$.widget('devall.popupManager', {
    /**
     * creating popup
     */
    _create: function () {
        var self = this,
        popupOptions = {
            responsive: true,
            title: this.options.popupTitle,
            buttons: false,
            modalClass: 'popup-devnewsletter',
            autoOpen: true,

            /**
             * setting a cookie
             */
            closed: function () {
                self._setCookie();
            }
        };

        if (!$.cookie('popup_cookie')) {
            modal(popupOptions, this.element);
        }

        this.element.find('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).validation('isValid')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    showLoader: true,

                    /**
                     * Just a function
                     */
                    success: function () {
                        self.element.modal('closeModal');
                        self._setCookie();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * cookie function
     */
    _setCookie: function () {
        var expDate = new Date();

        expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + 3650000 * 60 * 1000);
        $.cookie('popup_cookie', 1, {
            expires: expDate
        });
    }
});

return $.devall.popupManager;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$.cookie('popup_cookie')) {
                if (this.option.popupEvent === 2) {
                    $(document).mouseleave(function (e) {
                        var self = this;
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $(document).off('mouseleave');
                        modal(popupOptions, $('#popup-devnewsletter'));
                    });
                } else {
                    modal(popupOptions, $('#popup-devnewsletter'));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added that code in _create function

```
   if (this.options.dataPopup.isExitIntent) { //show when Exit Intent
                $(document).mouseleave(function () {
                    bioEp.init(self.options.dataPopup.popupConfig);
                    self._fullScreen();
                    $(document).off('mouseleave');
                    self._setDefaultSize();
                });
            }
```

now trying to stop (trigger)popup,because popup is shown but user can leave anyway.